# Problem with Android ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

i wrote a c++ program with make file in JNI folder.and wrote a program with SDK.

i want to use C++ library , but when i use it and run it on emulator i have error.it said i should use force exit.

C++ source : (wipeSRC.cpp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_X_XX_WF_Simple(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jstring addrs)
{
    return 1;
}
```

make file :

```
# makefile to pack JNI with AMR-NB native library
#

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := wipeLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wipeSRC.cpp


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and in SDK with JAVA :

```
package X.XX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WF extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Simple("hello");
    }
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("wipeLib");
    }

    native int Simple(String addrs);

}
```

Comment: Post the error message from logcat.

Comment: @Chris Strattom 
i am new in this field....
but i have no error in eclipse.
it s runtime.
out pu in eclipse is normal.
but when program luanched , it said the application .... has stopped unexpectedly.please try again.

Comment: You need to learn how to use logcat from the pc to see the error messages off the device. If you aren't finding any, you aren't looking in the right place, as the logs are quite "noisy" even when everything is working as well as it ever does.

Answer (score 0):

solved!
i used windows 7 last.but know i try windows XP.

solution is that :
use cygwin in windows 7 and copy library to win XP. then use XP to code in JAVA.at last problem will be solved.

i think it s better all programmers go to Linux. :D